# How to prevent the Music app from launching when pressed Play (F8) on keyboard is clicked in macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, keyboard, itunes, macos-ventura

As title describes, I would like to prevent Music app (previously known as iTunes) From launching and playing music when I accidentally press the <kbd>F8</kbd> (Play Button) on apple keyboard.

I am using macOS Ventura Version 13.0 with an Apple M1.

The previous method I used no longer in effect.

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

Edit:
The pause function must retained, such as pause youtube and other player when supported. But the launch music app need to be disabled.

Comment: I just tried `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist` on my MacBook Air (Intel) running macOS Ventura and it works fine. I click F8 and Music doesn’t launch. And if I change that `unload` to `load` again, it works again.

Answer (score 2):

This is more for the people who are looking for an answer. Type this into your terminal (worked for me on MacOS 13.2.1 with the new M1 chips)

```sh
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

I got this from https://gaborhargitai.hu/disable-itunes-keyboard-shortcutsmedia-buttons-on-macos/

To reenable:

```sh
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

---

What does `launchctl` do? I believe this is like `systemctl` on Ubuntu if anyone is familiar with that.

https://ss64.com/osx/launchctl.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this completely disables media keys, not just iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Flip the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key pref…

[image]

System preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Function Keys
Switch this on to make launching Music require a 2-key press, <kbd>Fn</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd>
Pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> alone will do nothing.

Comment: This also adds inconvenience to using other special features (volume and brightness adjustment).

Comment: It's an either/or, there's no granularity. At least this method doesn't unload the entire plist, making the whole set unavailable.

Comment: This is not the correct method. It would cause many side effects.